# Issues with nvidia graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04

I was geeting a blank screen when opening the nvidia x server app. I tried opening it from the terminal and got this error:

```
$ nvidia-settings -V

WARNING: NV-CONTROL extension not found on this Display.


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:3427): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:42:37.834: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 19:42:37.838: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 19:42:37.838: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

**I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.**
**I have nvidia geforce 1650 graphics card.**

Please help me with this!

Comment: Check if you are using proprietary drivers. You can check it through the 'Livepatch' app, in the 'Additional Drivers' tab.
Select nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Did you install " third party software " in OS installation ?

You can try to delete your not recognized graphics, but more easy is a fresh new OS installation and let system choose right drivers. Install via `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` won't enough to completely purge files and paths. Nothing other works for me. Feel free to choose Normal or Minimal installation in first step of this window.

[image]